# Why is it false that every function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ has a standard matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I ran into this problem in my Linear Algebra book while covering linear transformations:

True or False: Every function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ has a standard matrix.

I said true because if for the input of the function you give it row $i$ of the identity matrix you will get row $i$ of the standard matrix. Standard matrix $=[T(e_1) T(e_2) \cdots T(e_n)]$. I can't think of an example where we have a linear transformation where that's not the case. Am I interpreting the question incorrectly?

Comment: Not all functions (as the question is about) are linear (as in your argument).

Comment: Okay so i misunderstood the problem, thank you.

Comment: Could you provide a function where row i of the identity matrix doesnt give the standard matrix? My book provided a function that isnt a linear transformation but when i use row i of the identity matrix i still get row i of the standard matrix.

Comment: Take $m=n=1$ and $f(x)=x^2$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott could you give an example as a matrix transformation induced by A?

Comment: @Bubbletea: I don’t know what you mean: the whole point is that this is a function that **cannot** be represented by a matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some intuition that may help.

- Linear functions always have a matrix representation.
- Nonlinear functions never have a matrix representation.

You can think of linear functions as transformations that map squares to parallelograms, or cubes to parallelipipeds, or hyper-cubes to hyper-parallelipipeds, and so forth depending on the dimensions of the domain and range.

[image]

To find the matrix representation of a linear map, you just put the images of the unit vectors (eg, red and blue vectors in the upper right image) into a matrix, column by column.